# categorical encoding in h2o - test set

Tags: r, h2o

I'm using `h2o` in R to fit a gbm model to my data. I have a couple of categorical variables and i'm using the option `categorical_encoding` in the `h2o.gbm` function to encode these variables.

When dealing with predictions in test set, how I handle categorical variables? It seems that the function `predict`doesn't have an option that automatically encode categorical variables.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about H2O is that you don't have to worry about manual categorical encoding. `h2o.predict()` will apply the same categorical encoding method that was specified during training. For more information on how to set the type of categorical encoding during training please see the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/categorical_encoding.html) .